# Access local computer Web Server with a domain not IP

Tags: windows, apache, iis

Here in our company we have a computer with Win7 (not Server) running XAMPP (PHP) and ASP (IIS) for two applications. Different ports for each one, of course. So, this computer all the employees need to access with an IP like "172.XX.XX.XX:8090/etc/etc/xxxx". I want to know if have some way to change all this IP address to a domain name, like "ourcompany/etc/etc/xxx". It will make the employees life more easy. I've done some searches and found something with the "hosts" file of computer. But, as I know, it will change only for the computer access, to access without "localhost", but other users not from the computer will not access with "localhost" anyway, and yes with the IP, right?

Comment: The word you're looking for is "DNS". If you want to redirect the port 8090 to 80, you'll have to set up a proxy or bind to that hostname and port.

Comment: Hi @CodeCaster thanks for your reply. I don't want to redirect the ports, only change the IP address to a domain name, just for make it easier for users access and remember.

Comment: Yeah so look into DNS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every computer is on the same network you don't need DNS. The network discovery is giving you the name of the computer anyway.

You can find out the name easily with this cmd command:

```
open cmd.exe
set | find "COMPUTERNAME"
```

or if you are a part of a domain(eg Active Director)

```
open cmd.exe
set | find "COMPUTERNAME"
set | find "USERDNSDOMAIN"
```

The value of computername and userdnsdomain concatenated are your "domain name" you're looking for. Every computer which is in the same domain(Active Directory) can access the computer.

Comment: Perfect! It is on the same domain, just changing the computer name it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1 : try free/commercial DNS solution

Maybe [MaraDNS](http://maradns.samiam.org/download.html) will help you. It is a security-aware DNS server. [Here](http://blog.mixu.net/2009/10/14/how-to-setup-a-lan-dns-server-using-maradns-under-windows-7/) is a good tutorial on how to set it up on Windows 7.

There are also lots of DNS software like BIND, PowerDNS, Posadis or Unbound.

Simple DNS Server and Microsoft DNS looks really nice (but are not cheap).

## Solution 2 :  Install Windows Server

Microsoft DNS is included with Windows Server, you may virtualize such a server.

## Solution 3 : MacGyver approved solution

If you have static IPs, placing the same hosts file on every computer is a cheap solution : `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

- Put a static IP on the PC where the applications are running.
- Modify hosts file (c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts) in **ALL** of the computers that you want to give access including where the apps are running. For example:

> 27.11.250.15       server.com

The IP address must not have a port, and this configuration must be the same on each PC.

If you want to access a specific port you should type in the web navigator:

```
   server.com:8090
```

Take in advance: If for some reason the IP in the apps PC change you must change all hosts files like before including the new IP address.